# Where does Cardano Wallet stores created wallets in the node?

Tags: wallet

I'm running the Cardano node and Cardano wallet in the same EC2 instance. I did create a couple of wallets, however, I couldn't figure out where and how it stores created wallets in the node. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me the path that I need to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [start cardano-wallet](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet/#creating-a-wallet-with-cardano-wallet) you specify the wallet-db folder on the command line, that DB is where your private keys are saved (private key is encrypted using your spending password before saving)

Comment: Thank you! They are stored in db-folder as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

"Wallets" are not stored on the blockchain. You need to make a transaction to an address of your wallet. This will create a transaction, which is stored on the blockchain.

Comment: When I create a wallet via `walletServer.createOrRestoreShelleyWallet` I can see the wallets created in that Wallet Server by typing `cardano-wallet wallets list` and if I try to use that wallet in another wallet server it will not be visible because it is created in another wallet server. Therefore, I'd like to know the logic behind where the `cardano-wallet wallets list` command gets the created wallets in that server.

Comment: Ah seems like I misunderstood your question. Could you please provide a link to the cardano-wallet you're using?

Comment: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js This is the source that I use WalletServer or Cardano Wallet CLI doesn't matter. I just need to know where this response gets this wallet info in the node.